# Using percent width for Rcharts

Tags: rcharts

I was wondering how to set the width of an rChart using % as opposed to px. I noticed in the source code that it defaults to pixels. I'm trying to use it in a shiny app, and fixed with charts seem to be an issue as they don't scale with the rest of the user interface. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be considered a hack, since neither `rCharts` or most of the libraries have built in responsive behavior.  However, one change would be to define your own renderChart function with this behavior.  Something like this might work if you define in the server piece of shiny.

```
renderChart_pct <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
  func <- shiny::exprToFunction(expr, env, quoted)
  function() {
    rChart_ <- func()
    cht_style <- sprintf("<style>.rChart {width: %s; height: %s} </style>",
                         #### change these here to desired %
                         "100%", "100%")
    cht <- paste(capture.output(rChart_$print()), collapse = '\n')
    HTML(paste(c(cht_style, cht), collapse = '\n'))
  }
}
```

Then use `renderChart_pct` instead of `renderChart2`. You'll probably notice that the result will not be truly responsive.  Altogether, here would be an example with `dPlot`.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(rCharts)

  renderChart_pct <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
    func <- shiny::exprToFunction(expr, env, quoted)
    function() {
      rChart_ <- func()
      cht_style <- sprintf("<style>.rChart {width: %s; height: %s} </style>",
                           "100%", "100%")
      cht <- paste(capture.output(rChart_$print()), collapse = '\n')
      HTML(paste(c(cht_style, cht), collapse = '\n'))
    }
  }

  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
        h1("Filler Header") 
      )
      ,column(8,
        div (
          showOutput("myChart", "dimple")
        )
      )
    )
  ))

  server = function(input,output){
    output$myChart <- renderChart_pct({
      d = dPlot(
        x~x
        , data = data.frame(x=1:10)
        , type = "line"
        , height = 500
        , width = NULL
      )
    })
  }

  runApp( list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: great solution and it seems to work for the mot part. I am using nvd3 and `nplot()` to create my chart and for some reason only half the chart seems to show on screen. Any thoughts?